# How to find index of the first match in the column using Google sheets script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to find index of the first match in the column using Google sheets script:

```
function getRowIndex() {
  var lookupValue = "car";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("List");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lookupRangeValues = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, 1).getValues()[0];
  var index = lookupRangeValues.indexOf(lookupValue);
  Logger.log(index);
}
```

But my code returns -1 always. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in

`var lookupRangeValues = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, 1).getValues()[0];`

you ask for first row.

`getValues()` return a 2D array as so:

`array[rowIndex][columnIndex]`

try:

```
function getRowIndex() {
  var lookupValue = "car";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("List");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lookupRangeValues = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, 1).getValues();
  var index = -1;
  lookupRangeValues.forEach(function (row, i){
     if (row[0] == lookupValue )
     {
       index = i;
       return (false);
     }
  });
  Logger.log(index);
}
```