# Read Date as String from Google Sheet cell in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of dates in one of the column of my sheet which is sorted already. I am reading all the cells of the column and trying to find first occurrence of a given date (using this answer to find first occurrence https://stackoverflow.com/a/52995342)

Here is my code on reading all cell value....

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var rawDataSheetObj = ss.getSheetByName("DateSheet");

// I am reading all the dates from Column A
// Any cell in Column A will have value in "MM/DD/YYYY" format
var lookupDates = rawDataSheetObj.getRange("A1:A").getValues()
Logger.log("Date : " + lookupDates[0][0])
```

So output is something like this

`Date : Wed Jan 18 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)`

instead of

`Date : 01/18/2023`

So How do I read a cell value as string so google app script doesn't mess up the value?

Comment: In your script, please replace `getValues()` with `getDisplayValues()` and test it again. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked as expected. Can you put this as answer? So I can accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. In this case, there is a duplicated thread. For example, it is https://stackoverflow.com/q/55820390 So, I would like to flag it as a duplicated question instead of posting it as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's a better option to mark it as duplicate. Thank for the help.